# SQL query to select multiple values from one table and assign to second table value

Tags: sql-server, join

I have three tables and want to assign value of table a to concurrent values of table b based on condition of col6 and col9.

Table a

```
Col1 col2 col3
A1    aa.  S1
B1.   Fh.  S1
C1.   Gs.  S2
D1.   Hh.  S1
A2.   Sg.  S2
C2.   Dh.  S2
```

Table b

```
Col4 col5 col6
A1.   Aa.  P1
A2.   Ab.  P2
B1.   Aa.  P2
C1.   Ac.  P3
C2.   Ab.  P1
D1.   Ab.  P3
```

Table c

Col7.   col8. Col9
I1.    Aa.   30
I2.    Ab.   10
I3.    Ac.   15
I4.    Ac.   30
I5.    Ac.   10
I6.    Ab.   5
I7.    Ab.   30
I8.    Ab.   1
I9.    Ac.   20
I10.   Aa.   25

Table a and table b have matching column as col1 and col4 respectively and table b and table c have matching column as col5 and col8 respectively.

I want to assign values to cola from table a with values of col7 from table c based on
Col6 order and col9 order.

If values of col6 is smaller and col9 is larger, it should be assign first like (P1 and 30).

Most we can assign 2 values to one row. And can assign in continuation if filled with two

I want a output as

```
O1       o4
A1.   I1, I10
A2.   I6,I8
B1.   
C1.   I4,I9
D1.   
C2.   I7, I2
```

And so on

Comment: Is this sql server ?

Comment: Its not clear to me what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL SERVER :

```
with Table_A_rn as (
  select *,  ( row_number() over ( order by (select null) ) - 1 )  / 2 as rn
  from Table_A
),
Table_B_rn as (
  select *, row_number() over ( order by (select null) ) - 1 as rn
  from Table_B
)
select b.Col4 AS Col1, STRING_AGG(a.Col1, ',') as Col4
from Table_A_rn a
inner join Table_B_rn b on a.rn = b.rn
group by b.Col4
```

Result :

```
Col1 |  Col4
------------
N1. A1,B1.
N2. C1.,D1.
N3. A2.,C2.
```

`Table_A_rn` will create same row number for every two successif records using the formule `(row_number - 1 / 2)`, the created row numbers will start from 0.

`Table_B_rn` to create row number for Table_B starting from 0.

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/PaBCzG7S)